# VimScript "unknown function" on a lot of functions

Tags: vimscript, neovim

So I have been writing a vim extension but it simply does not make sense to me. I am using nvim and [clearly see the function chansend in the documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/eval.html#chansend()) yet I get "Unknown function: chansend" when trying to call it. Seems trivial but simply does not exist, any help?

Comment: this is a case of new documentation, old neovim.   you may want to use the development v0.3.0 version

Comment: @Mass Seems like a stupid decision to push documentation of the git version rather than the latest stable version. Apparently I need to check out old documentation to be able to write a backwards-compatible vim plugin then, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jobsend()` is the previous name for `chansend()` (changed in [5af47031](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/5af47031773fc647de867444693d1598d0da458d)).  It will still work, but is not documented anymore to nudge people towards using `chansend()`.

You can detect which is available and then use the appropriate one.

```
if exists('*chansend')
    let s:Send = function('chansend')
else
    let s:Send = function('jobsend')
endif
call s:Send(job, data)
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but I am running 0.2.2 which is the latest release so it seems like chansend should be available (but apparently it isn't as the commit has the nighly tag I guess). Very annoying. jobsend still doesn't work for me but that's a seperate issue I guess, so thanks for the help!